# Volume of a pencil

Tags: geometry

A pencil sharpened at both ends is formed of a cylindrical barrel together with two conical points. The pencil measures 110mm from tip to tip, has radius $r$ mm, and the cylindrical barrel is $h$ mm long. The lengths of the conical sharpened points are $x$ mm and $y$ mm. Show that the total volume $V$ $mm^3$ of the pencil is given by the formula

$$V=(2\pi r^2(55+h))/3$$

and explain why the volume does not depend on the lengths of the sharpened points.

All help and solutions are heavily appreciate (been working on this for over an hour and just keep coming up with solutions that do not lead anywhere)!

Thank you.

Comment: What are you calling "conical points" ?

Comment: cones.           random words to write comment

Comment: Your comment is hard to understand. I ask my question in another way : you mean that the extremities of the pencil are vertices of cones, is it that ?

Comment: yes, you are correct

Comment: Well, obviously x+y = 110 -h.  One cone end has volume 1/3 BaseArea x x.  And the other one 1/3 BaseArea x y.  So the volume of the two cone ends is 1/3 BaseArea x (x+y)= 1/3 BaseArea x (110-h) so the individual heights of the two cone doesn't matter.  Just the sum of the two heights.  The volume of cylindrical barrel is BaseArea x h.  So the total volume is BaseArea  (1/3[110-h] +h]) That's easily manipulable to the final anse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The volume of a cylinder with radius $r$ and height $h$ is $\pi r^2 h$. The volume of a right circular cone with base radius $r$ and height $x$ is $\frac{1}{3} \pi r^2 x$.

Then, the total volume of the pencil is $\pi r^2 h + \frac{1}{3} \pi r^2 x + \frac{1}{3} \pi r^2 y = \pi r^2 ( h + \frac{x + y}{3})$.

Note that $x + y = 110 - h$ and simplify.

Comment: Could you please continue this for me as I am still stuck.

Comment: Substitute $110 - h$ for $x + y$ and manipulate. You know the equation you are trying to reach, so it shouldn't be too hard to get there.

Comment: I get pir^2(2h+110/3)

Comment: and then 2(pir^2(h+110)/3))

Comment: Your first equation is correct, but you haven't factored out the 2 properly in the second one.

Comment: Oh I understand now. Thank you